# Identifying anonymous structs and their elements in an LLVM pass

Tags: c, struct, clang, llvm

I am writing an LLVM pass where I first process debug information by looking for `DbgDeclareInst` instructions (I compile with `-O0 -g -gfull`). I am able to identify structs, their names, and their elements. I maintain a map keyed by name, where the value is a class that holds the name of the struct and the names of its elements.

When the source has anonymous structs, I get an empty string when I do `type->getName()` while processing a debug-declare instruction involving an anonymous struct. This is mentioned in the documentation. But it presents a problem because later I try to identify variables that have been modified by looking for `StoreInst` instructions. I am able to deal with structs by checking to see if the pointer operand to the store instruction is a `GetElementPtrInst` and if the source element type is `StructType`. I can get the struct name from the type and the element index from the `gep` instruction, and then use them to look up the struct information in my map to see which struct element is getting modified.

Since the map is keyed by name this is obviously a problem for anonymous structs because I don't know what to look up. I thought that since `StructType` returns elements, I could figure out which element is being modified if I am dealing with an anonymous struct. But that didn't work because the elements are also `Type*` and so only specify the type and not the name of the struct element. Is there any way I can go from `StructType` to the corresponding `DIType`?

I tried to detect whether a structure is anonymous by checking if the name of the type was `struct.anon` (or `struct.anon.N` where N is some number -- this is when there are multiple anonymous structs) because I saw that in the LLVM IR that's what anonymous structs end up being named. However that is a problem if the code has a struct actually named `anon`. Then it may also end up being named `struct.anon` or `struct.anon.N` if there already are exist some other anonymous structs. This means it is hard to distinguish it from an real anonymous struct.

Is there any way I can tell whether a `StructType` represents an anonymous struct, or is there a way to get the actual names of the elements of the struct from `StructType`? I am not able to use `structType->hasName()` because that is returning true even for anonymous structs (since they do end up being named at this point with the special `anon` name). From the IR it appears this is not possible directly since it only maintains the types of the elements without any element names. So as I mentioned earlier, going from `Type*` to `DIType*` would be useful here. Is that possible? The debug information on the `StoreInst` only tells me on what line the variable was modified.

I am using LLVM 10.

Comment: Just in general it is not always possible to go from `Type *` to `DIType *`: there are cases where the struct is generated by a compiler and does not exist on the high level. The way to resolve `anon` ambiguity is to track whether your map has a struct named `anon` or not. But again, generally speaking, there might be many 'false positives'.

Comment: I think the best way to proceed here may be to compile a largish program, take all the structtypes in the IR form, connect them to their source form by inspection (or deciding that no source exists), and then use that list to try to formulate rules that can be implemented and will match your purpose.

Comment: Thanks @AlexDenisov I was trying something like this. It would be nice if the LLVM API exposed something that could really tell me if I was dealing with an actual anonymous struct.

Comment: Thanks @arnt this is the direction I was thinking of going as well. I was hoping there was an easier way.

Comment: Is there no hasName() method? I am surprised.

Comment: There is a `hasName`, but it returns `true` even for anonymous structs because by this point they have been named `anon`, `anon.0`, and so on. I wonder if it is an artifact of including debugging information that it ends up naming them that way.

Comment: The "anon.X" is not related to the debug information. You will get the same ''clash' even for 'normal' named structs if you load two modules into the same context. Some time ago I had to solve a related problem. It is described [here](https://lowlevelbits.org/type-equality-in-llvm/) in more details,

Comment: @AlexDenisov right if there are multiple anonymous structures in the same module they get the name `anon`, `anon.0`, etc. I was just talking about the `anon` part. I know that if you have two normal, named structs with clashing names they will also have `.0` suffixed to them.

Comment: @AlexDenisov thank you for the link to your blog post. It is really helpful!